# Rails respond to ajax request before end of action

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

What I would like to do is have my multiTest action respond to the ajax request before parsing the json it got from the request and put it in the database. putting data in the database is causing a long wait time. responding to ajax at the `render json: @toTest` should help speed my application significantly. fyi the params data is an Array of objects

```
 def multitest
    @toTest = PrimeNumber.last
    @toTest.testNumber = @toTest.testNumber + (2 * $loc) 
    $loc += $increment
    render json: @toTest

    parameters = params.first
    parameters = parameters[1]
    parameters.each do |pn|
        prime = PrimeNumber.new
        prime.testNumber = pn[:prime_number]["testNumber"]
        prime.isPrime = pn["prime_number"]["isPrime"]
        prime.wasTested = true
        prime.checkTime = Time.now
        prime.save
    end
    $loc -= $increment
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the params processing into a background process with: 
[sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) or [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque).